# INTEGRATION-type problem-Find the value of $\int_0^8f(t)dt$

Tags: integration

If the function $f:[0,8] → R$ is differentiable then for $0<\alpha$, $\beta<2$ , $\int_0^8f(t)dt$ is equal to

(A) $3[\alpha^3f(\alpha^2)+\beta^3f(\beta^2)]$

(B) $3[\alpha^3f(\alpha^2)+\beta^3f(\beta)]$

(C) $3[\alpha^2f(\alpha^3)+\beta^2f(\beta^3)]$

(D) $3[\alpha^2f(\alpha^2)+\beta^2f(\beta^2)]$

Comment: I don’t see a connection between the condition of dufferentiability and the analytic expression of definite integral. Is it possible you omitted something in this exercise, like additional info on function f?

Answer (score 3):

We are given $f:[0,8]\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable and $0<\alpha$, $\beta<2$. Let

$$g(x)=\int_0^{x^3}f(t)\,dt$$
then

$$g(2)=\int_0^8f(t)\,dt=g(2)-g(1)+g(1)-g(0)$$

since $g(0)=0$. This implies

$$g(2)=\frac{g(2)-g(1)}{2-1}+\frac{g(1)-g(0)}{1-0}$$

As $f:[0,8]\to\mathbb R$ is differentiable, g must also be differentiable on some $[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ so we can apply the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) to write

$$g'(x)=\frac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}$$

thus

$$g(2)=\int_0^8f(t)\,dt=g'(\alpha)+g'(\beta)$$

where $\alpha\in[1,2]$ and $\beta\in[0,1]$. So, by the [first fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part),
$$g'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{x^3}f(t)\,dt=3x^2f(x^3)$$
therefore
$$g'(\alpha)=3\alpha^2f(\alpha^3), \quad g'(\beta)=3\beta^2f(\beta^3)$$
which implies
$$g(2)=\int_0^8f(t)\,dt=g'(\alpha)+g'(\beta)=3\left[\alpha^2f(\alpha^3)+ \beta^2f(\beta^3)\right]$$